# parsing hash references in perl

Tags: perl

I've question with perl hashes, any advice on this is greatly appreciated- below is just the code snippet --

```
my @results = $sp->get_list_items($listid, $viewid); 
print Dumper @results;
```

output is something like this,

```
$VAR1 = { a => 1, b => 2, g => 1, }; 
$VAR2 = { c => 1, d => 2, g => 1, b => 1434, h => 2 }; 
$VAR3 = { e => 1, a => 232, f => 2 }; 
$VAR4 = { g => 1, h => 2, a => 5, b => 19 };
```

Note: it's a semicolon and not comma between the hash references!! My task is to gather a and b values from each hashref(replace it by 0 if a or b doesn't exist in a hashref) and store it in a hash, it's easy if hashrefs are joined by comma since it's a semicolon it made this real tough for me in spite of multiple trials, please help..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are misinterpreting the output of `Data::Dumper`. You need to send the array ref to the Dumper function:

```
print Dumper \@results;
```

Otherwise, you send the list of elements in the array to be printed individually.

You should get output like this:

```
$VAR1 = [
          {
            'a' => 1,
            'g' => 1,
            'b' => 2
          },
          {
            'c' => 1,
            'h' => 2,
            'b' => 1434,
            'g' => 1,
            'd' => 2
          },
          {
            'e' => 1,
            'a' => 232,
            'f' => 2
          },
          {
            'a' => 5,
            'h' => 2,
            'b' => 19,
            'g' => 1
          }
        ];
```

Comment: `Super! I just used print statement to see the output of @results, from this point, my @results = $sp->get_list_items($listid, $viewid); I'm not sure how to interpret the @results output to create a hash   consisting of a and b...thanks a lot for helping.`

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget to accept the answer if you feel it solved your problem.

Comment: `I'm satisfied with your earlier answer, but my question is still open ---> From this point, my @results = $sp->get_list_items($listid, $viewid); I'm not sure how to interpret the @results output to create a hash consisting of a and b`

Comment: You iterate over the array and collect a/b values or 0 if they dont exist. You know you dont have to use code formatting in comments.

Comment: BTW, @TOM, you don't need to mark your whole comment as `code`. :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you want to 'store the a and b values in a hash', but this should give  you something to start with:

```
for my $result (@results) {
  my $a_val = $result->{a} || 0;
  my $b_val = $result->{a} || 0;

  # now do something with $a_val and $b_val ...

}
```